# Virtuoso 42000 Error when using dbpedia sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I wrote a query in DBpedia SPARQL:

```
select distinct ?s 
where {
?s rdf:type dbo:Writer.
?s rdf:type yago:LivingPeople.
?s dbo:birthDate ?year.
FILTER (?year > 1964-01-01).
}
```

but it is showing:

> Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 82850 (sec) exceeds the limit of 240 (sec).

What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem -- processing the query is expected to take 82850 seconds, but the server is set to only run for 240 seconds.

You can solve this by changing your query to something that runs more quickly, or by setting up your own mirror of the public DBpedia service, [most easily done in the Amazon cloud](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015).

That said...  I've just tested your query against the live DBpedia endpoint, and [it comes back nearly instantly](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20dbo%3AWriter%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20yago%3ALivingPeople%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%20%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%20%3Fyear%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fyear%20%3E%201964-01-01%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To workaround it I setup a [SPARQL server](https://github.com/tenforce/docker-virtuoso) in my local.